# How to run kapacitor commands in a kubernetes environment?

Tags: kubernetes, kapacitor

When starting kapacitor (influxdata) in a docker container, the kapacitor daemon is started and runs in the foreground.

To run kapacitor commands, one needs to `exec` into the docker container and run commands like `kapacitor define backup_alert ....; kapacitor enable ...`

Now I'm trying to start the kapacitor container in the kuberneter environment, which runs fine. The problem I'm facing is how to run the additional commands like `kapacitor define`.

I've tried to modify the entrypoint/command, but I run into the fact that once the kapacitor daemon (`kapacitord`) is started, it doesn't accepts any kapacitor commands because the daemon is running in the foreground.

How should I solve this?

Comment: _> one needs to exec into the docker container_    Have you tried `kubectl exec -it ThePodName -- sh -il`? That is the k8s replacement for `docker exec`

Comment: That seems to solve (part) of the problem. I suppose kapacitor can use some improvements to help provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kubectl port-forward to forward kapacitor port to your local machine and use kapacitor binary locally.

*Terminal 1*

```
kubectl port-forward <kapacitor-pod-id> 9092
```

*Terminal 2*

```
kapacitor list tasks
```